# How to make parent stretch the given space that a child needs?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I don't really care (right now) what the parent element needs to be, I just need it to be able to stretch based on whatever text I have. Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
public CustomCommentCell()
    {
        CommentContainer = new Xamarin.Forms.Grid();
        CommentText = new Xamarin.Forms.Label();
        SetCellLayout();

    }

    private void SetCellLayout()
    {
        CommentContainer.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.ColumnDefinition { Width = new Xamarin.Forms.GridLength(1, Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Star) });
        CommentContainer.RowDefinitions.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.RowDefinition { Height = new Xamarin.Forms.GridLength(100, Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Star) });
        CommentContainer.Children.Add(CommentText);

        View = CommentContainer;
    }
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        try
        {
            var item = BindingContext as XamarinMobile.ViewModels.CommentsCellViewModel;

            if (item == null)
                return;

            CommentContainer.BackgroundColor = item.Level == 0 ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Gray : Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("d3d3d3");
            CommentContainer.Padding = new Xamarin.Forms.Thickness(10);
            CommentContainer.Margin = item.Level == 0 ? new Xamarin.Forms.Thickness(10) : new Xamarin.Forms.Thickness(25, 10, 10, 10);
            CommentText.VerticalOptions = CommentContainer.VerticalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CommentText))
            {
                CommentText.Text = item.CommentText;
            }

            //Height = 100;
        } catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            var j = ex;
        }
    }
```

I am using a ListView coupled with caching strategy set to `recycle`. Which is why my view is in a class like this. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rows of your ListView are of the same size, you could simply add `RowHeight = [SomeHeight]` in your ListView.

If they are of different sizes, you have to add `HasUnevenRows = true` in your ListView and in the ViewCell's OnBindingContextChanged you have to add `Height = [ViewCellHeight]`.

And if you are asking about the text height based on number of lines, Xamarin doesn't check the number of lines, so I think that the fourth post of this thread is the best you can get: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20308/how-do-we-use-the-new-listview-hasunevenrows-property-to-fit-height-to-content-on-ios.

A resumed version of the post:

```
// Roughly calculate the height based on the number of chars
if (MultinlineLabel.Length > 75)
    this.Height = 110;
else if (MultinlineLabel.Length > 60)
    this.Height = 80;
else if (MultinlineLabel.Length > 30)
    this.Height = 60;
else
    this.Height = 40;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't know the ViewCellHeight, or what it should be. Otherwise, this wouldn't be an issue :P. I appreicate your findings though.

Comment: Marking your answer as correct because the link you contained does have a valid solution. You might want to include the EstimateHeight method in your answer to help others, but it seems to accurately estimate the height needed. No android/windows solution though but works for iOS.

Comment: Actually, the code contained in the link is cross-platform. It only checks the length of some string and set the height of the label based on that. To make it better, you could create a custom control that extends Label and add a read-only property that returns the approximate number of lines based on its width and font size. I didn't try to do that so I can't say what's the best formula, but it should work.